# android paste event

Tags: android, events, paste

Is there a way to catch the paste event in my application? I must do something when I click long on an editText and select Paste from context menu. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create menu.xml with position 'paste'

Register contextMenu to your EditText

```
EditText et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et);
registerForContextMenu(et);
```

Create contextMenu

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);    
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;  
    menu.setHeaderTitle("title");
}
```

Create method menu onClick

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();     
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.paste:      
        break;     
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I know this thread is old, but doesn't this replace the built-in context menu with your own context menu?  What if you like that menu, but just want to be notified when a paste happens?

Comment: @ScottBiggs It also works without re-creating the menu. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14981376/717341)

Comment: Please have a look at my question too https://stackoverflow.com/q/76520789/4134215

Answer (score 2):

You should implement a *TextWatcher* listener on the control that receives the paste action.

The *TextWatcher* class provides methods to handle the OnChange, BeforeChange and AfterChange of any Editable. For instance:

```
private void pasteEventHandler() {
    ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtOutput))
            .addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Text changed, refreshing view.");
                    refreshView();
                }

                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                        int count, int after) {
                }

                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                        int before, int count) {
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Just a pedantic comment:  casting to a TextView is enough.

Comment: This doesn't answer the user's question in my opinion.
With this you'll be listening for typing, erasing , pasting, etc

Answer (score 2):

Below is code where you can override actionbar copy/Paste etc.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    EditText editText;
    private ClipboardManager myClipboard;
    private ClipData myClip;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myClipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);

        myClipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        editText.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new Callback() {

            @Override
            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case android.R.id.copy:
                    int min = 0;
                    int max = editText.getText().length();
                    if (editText.isFocused()) {
                        final int selStart = editText.getSelectionStart();
                        final int selEnd = editText.getSelectionEnd();

                        min = Math.max(0, Math.min(selStart, selEnd));
                        max = Math.max(0, Math.max(selStart, selEnd));
                    }
                    // Perform your definition lookup with the selected text
                    final CharSequence selectedText = editText.getText()
                            .subSequence(min, max);
                    String text = selectedText.toString();

                    myClip = ClipData.newPlainText("text", text);
                    myClipboard.setPrimaryClip(myClip);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Text Copied",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // Finish and close the ActionMode
                    mode.finish();
                    return true;
                case android.R.id.cut:
                    // add your custom code to get cut functionality according
                    // to your requirement
                    return true;
                case android.R.id.paste:
                    // add your custom code to get paste functionality according
                    // to your requirement
                    return true;

                default:
                    break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });         
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set Listener Class:

```
public interface GoEditTextListener {
void onUpdate();
```

}

Сreate self class for EditText:

```
public class GoEditText extends EditText
{
    ArrayList<GoEditTextListener> listeners;

    public GoEditText(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        listeners = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public GoEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        listeners = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public GoEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        listeners = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addListener(GoEditTextListener listener) {
        try {
            listeners.add(listener);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Here you can catch paste, copy and cut events
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onTextContextMenuItem(int id) {
        boolean consumed = super.onTextContextMenuItem(id);
        switch (id){
            case android.R.id.cut:
                onTextCut();
                break;
            case android.R.id.paste:
                onTextPaste();
                break;
            case android.R.id.copy:
                onTextCopy();
        }
        return consumed;
    }

    public void onTextCut(){
    }

    public void onTextCopy(){
    }

    /**
     * adding listener for Paste for example
     */
    public void onTextPaste(){
        for (GoEditTextListener listener : listeners) {
            listener.onUpdate();
        }
    }
}
```

xml:

```
<com.yourname.project.GoEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/editText1"/>
```

And in your activity:

```
private GoEditText editText1;

editText1 = (GoEditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

            editText1.addListener(new GoEditTextListener() {
                @Override
                public void onUpdate() {
//here do what you want when text Pasted
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Got callback of paste event in onActionItemClicked(mode:ActionMode, item:MenuItem)

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        editText.customInsertionActionModeCallback = object : ActionMode.Callback {
            override fun onActionItemClicked(mode: ActionMode?, item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
                Log.e("ActionMode", "::ItemClicked")
                if(item?.groupId == android.R.id.paste){
                    Log.e("ActionMode", "::Paste::ItemClicked")
                }
                return true
            }

            override fun onCreateActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu?): Boolean {
                Log.e("ActionMode", "::Created")
                return true
            }

            override fun onPrepareActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu?): Boolean {
                Log.e("ActionMode", "::Prepared")
                return true
            }

            override fun onDestroyActionMode(mode: ActionMode?) {
                Log.e("ActionMode", "::Destroyed")
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this code that I've create recently

```
        setOnReceiveContentListener(editText, arrayOf("text/*"),
        OnReceiveContentListener { view, payload ->
            if(view == editText && payload.source == ContentInfoCompat.SOURCE_CLIPBOARD && payload.clip.description.hasMimeType("text/*")) {
                var t=""
                for (i in 0 until payload.clip.itemCount) {
                    t += payload.clip.getItemAt(i).text
                }
                //do what ever you want to do with the text and set it to editText
                editText.setText(t)
                return@OnReceiveContentListener null
            } else
                return@OnReceiveContentListener payload
        }
    )
```

return the payload as it i, if not text and coming from clipboard to avoid any unintended intercepting