# Android intercept paste\copy\cut on editText

Tags: android, textview, android-edittext, textwatcher

How can I intercept this kind of events ?

I need to add some logic when the user trying to paste some text into my `EditText` i know i can use `TextWatcher` but this entrypoint not good for me becuase i only need to intercept in case of paste and not every time the user press my `EditText`,

Comment: Good challenge. Look at my answer.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Seems there isn't much you can do by using the API: [android paste event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167381/android-paste-event)

[**Source reading to the rescue!**](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/04/learn-to-read-the-source-luke.html)

I dug into the Android Source of the `TextView` (`EditText` is a `TextView` with some different configuration) and found out that the menu used to offer the cut/copy/paste options is just a modified [`ContextMenu`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextMenu.html) ([source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3_r1/android/widget/TextView.java#6756)).

As for a normal context-menu, the View must create the menu ([source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3_r1/android/widget/TextView.java#7386)) and then handle the interaction in a callback-method ([source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3_r1/android/widget/TextView.java#7516)).

Because the handling method is `public`, we can simply hook into it by extending `EditText` and overwriting the method to react on the different actions. Here is an example-implementation:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * An EditText, which notifies when something was cut/copied/pasted inside it.
 * @author Lukas Knuth
 * @version 1.0
 */
public class MonitoringEditText extends EditText {

    private final Context context;

    /*
        Just the constructors to create a new EditText...
     */
    public MonitoringEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public MonitoringEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public MonitoringEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        this.context = context;
    }

    /**
     * <p>This is where the "magic" happens.</p>
     * <p>The menu used to cut/copy/paste is a normal ContextMenu, which allows us to
     *  overwrite the consuming method and react on the different events.</p>
     * @see <a href="http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3_r1/android/widget/TextView.java#TextView.onTextContextMenuItem%28int%29">Original Implementation</a>
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onTextContextMenuItem(int id) {
        // Do your thing:
        boolean consumed = super.onTextContextMenuItem(id);
        // React:
        switch (id){
            case android.R.id.cut:
                onTextCut();
                break;
            case android.R.id.paste:
                onTextPaste();
                break;
            case android.R.id.copy:
                onTextCopy();
        }
        return consumed;
    }

    /**
     * Text was cut from this EditText.
     */
    public void onTextCut(){
        Toast.makeText(context, "Cut!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    /**
     * Text was copied from this EditText.
     */
    public void onTextCopy(){
        Toast.makeText(context, "Copy!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    /**
     * Text was pasted into the EditText.
     */
    public void onTextPaste(){
        Toast.makeText(context, "Paste!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Now, when the user uses cut/copy/paste, a `Toast` is shown (of course you could do other things, too).

The neat thing is that **this works down to Android 1.5** and you don't need to re-create the context-menu (like suggested in the above linked question), which will **keep the constant look of the platform** (for example with HTC Sense).

Comment: i got **can't instantiate class no empty constructor** error what solution of it ???

Comment: well, the class has no empty constructor. you have to pass it an instance of `Context` (if your code is in an Activity, you can pass it `this`).

Comment: Expanded your solution with a listener so it can be used as a plug&play component. The gist https://gist.github.com/guillermomuntaner/82491cbf0c88dec560a5

Comment: How to get the inserted Spanned String from the paste ?

Comment: @Pierre you could add a `TextWatcher` and record the changes. If a change occurs and you get a fitting cut/paste/copy action, you can figure out which part of the content changed.

Comment: Finally found out a better solution. I do not want a TextWatcher triggered each time a letter is pressed. So, I used the ClipBoardManager to override the pasted content. Thanks to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6651184/set-text-and-get-text-from-clipboard and https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste.html

Answer (score 8):

There is a **much simpler way**, although not 100% reliable.

Add TextChangedListener to your editbox:

```
EditText et = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.yourEditText);
et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

  @Override
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
     if (count > 2) toast("text was pasted");
  }

  @Override
  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

  }

  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
               
  }
});
```

If the text changes for more than 2 characters, you can assume it was pasted (some smileys take up two characters).

Of course it will not detect pasting when the user pastes 1 or 2 characters, and it will falsely report pasting if the change in text was triggered by something else.

But for **most purposes, it gets the job done**

Comment: This doesn't work if your edittext is limited to 1 char only and you want to copy to multiple edittexts ( like a code with 1 et for each digit)

Comment: tiagocarvalho92: yes, that is written in the description.

Comment: This seems ok. For I'd look into integrating with the system and maybe use auto-fill or that OTP provider thing that automatically reads the messages. It's a much better user experience. Also having a 'paste' button would do the trick. There's really no reason to be constrained to EditText in that scenario.