# how to disable paste option in android EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a requirement where `EditText` doesn't allow paste but it should allow copy.
I tried `setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback` but it disables the copy option.

```
EditText  etxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
etxt.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new Callback() {
             
            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                return false;
            }
 
            public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {                  
            }
 
            public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                return false;
            }
 
            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: how did u implement that?

Comment: Post the code you've tried

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/12331404/501483

Comment: @dhams:this should disable both copy and paste the question is to only disable paste functionality.

Comment: Follow this one is right answer:-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41673185/disable-edittext-context-menu

Answer (score 2):

I did it myself..credit goes to [Android intercept paste\copy\cut on editText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14980227/android-intercept-paste-copy-cut-on-edittext)

I just changed onTextContextMenuItem() based on my requirement..

```
@Override
    public boolean onTextContextMenuItem(int id) {
        // Do your thing:
        //boolean consumed = super.onTextContextMenuItem(id); // Change1
        // React:
        switch (id){
            case android.R.id.cut:
                onTextCut();
                break;
            case android.R.id.paste:
                onTextPaste();
                return false;       //Change2
                //break;
            case android.R.id.copy:
                onTextCopy();
        }
        return true; // Change3
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using API level 11 or above use this

```
      edittext.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new Callback() {

        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {                  
        }

        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: You should demonstrate to the OP how to use that.

Comment: what you mean? it wrks for me, just get the id of the edittext and do the above code :)

Comment: And what menu pops up?

Comment: I think the above code will restrict both copy and paste functionality.But the @surendra wants only to disable paste not copy operation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable only the paste option, I think it is better to remove the `paste context menu` item, this is a util method I implemented in my apps to achieve that (I also removed cut item)

```
    public static void toggleContextMenuType(EditText editText) {

    if (editText.getCustomSelectionActionModeCallback() == null) {
        editText.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionMode.Callback() {
            @Override
            public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                menu.removeItem(16908322);
                menu.removeItem(16908320);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            }
        });
    }else{
        editText.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't hard-code integer values of IDs, use Android constants for that: `android.R.id.paste` (16908322), `android.R.id.cut` (16908320)