# Disable Paste option in edittext when tapping cursor

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have set CustomSelectionActionModeCallback to an edittext as below

```
    new ActionMode.Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

    }
};
```

to disable paste option on edittext,but still user can paste by tapping on the cursor .I tried to create custom edittext class and override canPaste(),but still no luck.Can anybody suggest a correct solution.
Thanks.

Apparently the problem is observed in lollipop+ devices only

Comment: Check this once (http://stackoverflow.com/a/23101297/4988278) hope this is what you are looking for..

Comment: @MaheswaranS seems to be serving the purpose,but still PASTE option is displayed

Comment: Follow this one is right answer:-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41673185/disable-edittext-context-menu

Answer (score 0):

Another method one would suggest is to call `setLongClickable(false)` on the `EditText`, although that still doesn't prevent pasting from tapping on the cursor.

The proper (or only :) way to do this is to create a custom `EditText` and override `isSuggestionsEnabled` **and** `canPaste` methods.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28893714/3363481) answer for an example.