# Disable EditText context menu

Tags: android, android-edittext, contextmenu, mongolian-vertical-script

I am making a vertical `EditText` for traditional Mongolian. I have successfully implemented it by embedding a slightly modified `EditText` inside of a rotated `ViewGroup`. I need to create a completely custom context menu because the system one does not support vertical text and is also not rotated when the `ViewGroup` is rotated. So I want to disable the system context menu altogether.

Note that this is different than these questions that are just trying to disable copy/paste/etc.:

- [How to disable copy/paste from/to EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275299/how-to-disable-copy-paste-from-to-edittext)
- [EditText: Disable Paste/Replace menu pop-up on Text Selection Handler click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27869983/edittext-disable-paste-replace-menu-pop-up-on-text-selection-handler-click-even)
- [how to disable paste option in android EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23100691/how-to-disable-paste-option-in-android-edittext)
- [Android: How to TOTALLY disable copy and paste function in Edittext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26175041/android-how-to-totally-disable-copy-and-paste-function-in-edittext)

Although I don't get the context menu appearing in the simulator, I get it appearing in my Android 5.0.2 Xiaomi phone.

I have tried:

- [the `setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback` "solution"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22756538/3681880)
- [the `setLongClickable(false);` "solution"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13821250/3681880)
- [the `onTouchEvent` "solution"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30490027/3681880)

I'm open to hacks but I need it to consistently work across devices. Mark Murphy (a Commons Guy) [wrote](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/I2mh75F8cGY) some time back in reply to another user trying to do something similar:

> I suspect that even if you come up with an answer, it will not work
>   across devices. Device manufacturers have had a tendency to roll their
>   own "context menu" for EditText, defeating developers' attempts to add
>   items into that context menu. My guess is that trying to block that
>   context menu will have similar results.

Am I out of luck?

The only thing I can think of now is to completely rewrite `TextView` and `EditText` from scratch (well, by modifying the Android source). I know someone else who did something similar, but his code isn't open source. Before I take this major step, I want to try asking for a simpler solution here on Stack Overflow.

**Update:** I've been trying modify the `TextView` source code for the past two days and it looks like a 6 month project. It is a mass of interrelated classes. I need another solution, but I am out of ideas.

**MVCE**

This is the simplest way I could think of to recreate the problem. There is nothing necessary from my custom `EditText`. The layout has a single `EditText` made by replacing the default project Hello World's `TextView`. I changed the min API to 11 to avoid dealing with deprecated methods.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
        editText.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionMode.Callback() {
            @Override
            public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) { return false; }
            @Override
            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) { return false; }
            @Override
            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode actionMode, MenuItem menuItem) { return false; }
            @Override
            public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode actionMode) { }
        });
    }
}
```

The context menu in the simulator (running API 24) still shows when I click on the cursor handle (but not on a long click or double click). Here is an image:

[image]

On my Xiaomi MIUI phone running Android 5.0, I get the context menu in all situations (cursor handle click, long click, double click).

#### Update

Aritra Roy's solution is working in the simulator, on some other devices that he has tested, and on my device. I have accepted his answer because it solves my original problem. The only negative side effect is that text selection is also disabled.

Comment: Though probably not necessary to answer the question, my custom `EditText` code is [here on GitHub](https://github.com/suragch/Chimee/blob/develop/app/src/main/java/net/studymongolian/chimee/MongolEditText.java).

Comment: Is there a way for disable context menu on TextView?

Comment: who is Aritra Roy's and where is the answer

Comment: @MohdQasim, apparently that answer was deleted by a moderator supposedly for copying from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275299/how-to-disable-copy-paste-from-to-edittext and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27869983/edittext-disable-paste-replace-menu-pop-up-on-text-selection-handler-click-even/30490027#30490027

Answer (score 6):

the solution is very simple

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText et_0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    et_0 = findViewById(R.id.et_0);

    et_0.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionMode.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            //to keep the text selection capability available ( selection cursor)
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            //to prevent the menu from appearing
            menu.clear();
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

        }
    });
   }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I haven't tested this yet but it looks like the difference in your answer is that you are calling `menu.clear()`. What about when you click the cursor handles, long click, or double click? Does the menu appear?

Comment: @Suragch test it and let me know .

Comment: Works. Thank you!

Comment: I've tried the solution but when I perform a long click still appears the context menu

Comment: Not working....

Answer (score 5):

I have made this code for `EditText`, and it worked fine for such an issue.

```
try {
    edtName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            edtName.setSelection(0);
        }
    });
    edtName.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    edtName.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionMode.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) { return false; }
        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) { return false; }
        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode actionMode, MenuItem menuItem) { return false; }
        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode actionMode) { }
    });
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I tested your solution by replacing my code with yours in my MVCE above. On my Xiaomi MIUI Android 5.0 device this disables the context menu only for a long click. The menu still appears on a double click and when tapping on the cursor handle. I can't expect you to solve the problem for my specific device. I am just letting you know it is there. However, in the Android Studio emulator running API 24 I still get a menu showing when I click the cursor handle. I added an image to my answer above that shows this happening.

Answer (score 2):

```
mEditText.setLongClickable(false);
```

Its the simplest way to disable the edit text.

Comment: This may disable the context menu for a long click, but it doesn't disable it for a double tap or single click on the cursor.

Comment: Not working.....

Answer (score 2):

I also tackled this problem recently and I think I have the best solution for the usecase where we want to enable text selection and text select handles but remove the context menus completely.

There's two context menus

1. customInsertionActionModeCallback - (paste, select all)
2. customSelectionActionModeCallback - (cut, copy, share etc)

All the solutions target removing the second menu but not the one that the OP is asking which is the InsertionCallback when OP clicks on the cursor control thumb pin. To remove both callbacks, they both must be overridden

For SelectionCallback (cut, copy, paste)

```
customSelectionActionModeCallback = object : ActionMode.Callback {
    override fun onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        menu.clear()
        return true;
    }

   override fun onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        menu.clear();
        return false;
    }

   override fun onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        return false;
    }

    override fun onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

    }
```

Similarly, for InsertionCallback (selectAll, paste)

```
    customInsertionActionModeCallback = object : ActionMode.Callback { 
    override fun onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        menu.clear()
        return true;
    }

    override fun onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        menu.clear();
        return false;
    }

    override fun onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        return false;
    }

    override fun onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

    }
```

Comment: Awesome! There are a lot of answers on stackoverflow on this issue, but yours is the first to mention the function of both `customInsertionActionModeCallback` as well as `customSelectionActionModeCallback`. Most mention the latter and ignore the former or provide workarounds for the former. Your solution is the simplest and the most correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is how you block the copy paste menu from appearing in any way, shape or form. This bug really drove me crazy, and as with any Samsung bug you know its in their code but you also know they won't fix it any time soon. Anyways, here's wonder wall...

1. Check if Android.Build.Model.toLowerCase().startsWith('sm-g930').  Do not match the whole string, the last letter is a minor version identifier.  I stored this boolean in shouldBlockCopyPaste variable which comes up later.
2. If it matches you want to block the copy paste menu from showing.  This is how you ACTUALLY DO IT!!!

Override these 2 functions, you'll notice my shouldBlockCopyPaste boolean, this is so other devices dont get blocked.

```
   @Override
   public ActionMode StartActionMode (ActionMode.Callback callback){
      if (shouldBlockCopyPaste) {
        return null;
      } else {
        return super.StartActionMode(callback);
      }
    }

   @Override
   public ActionMode StartActionMode (ActionMode.Callback callback, int type){
      if (shouldBlockCopyPaste) {
        return null;
      } else {
        return super.StartActionMode(callback, type);
      }
    }
```

Comment: this did it for me!

Answer (score 1):

This is a hard problem. 
I've spent hours and hours researching and testing in my *Android Studio 3.4.2*.

I propose 3 steps:

**a)** the [setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback "solution"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22756538/3681880) in the original question
But it keeps showing the select handles (red drop under the cursor) and "Clipboard + Select All" popup, when you click in the red drop.

**b)** Create a empty image for select handles. I've created a file called `ic_empty.xml` under `res/drawable`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
</shape>
```

**c)**  I've created a style in `style.xml` for all `EditTexts`.

Under main theme

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        ...
        <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/TStyle</item>
        ....
 </style>
```

So you can define you style associating an empty image for lef, middle, and right select handles:

```
   <style name="TStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText" >
        <item name="android:textSelectHandle">@drawable/ic_empty</item>
        <item name="android:textSelectHandleLeft">@drawable/ic_empty</item>
        <item name="android:textSelectHandleRight">@drawable/ic_empty</item>
    </style>
```

If the target is from `API 23` one can use `setTextAppearance` for attach a style in a text inside a `EditText`. However, the above solution works always

The only remaining problem is that I can rid of double click effect. It selects a word in the text, with pink background. However, it is relatively harmless, but awkward, because it does not require user interaction.

A trick that can be done it's set the highlight color transparent.

```
EditT.setHighlightColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)  // EditT is a EditText
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the answers above, but I did not get a complete solution.
If you want do disable only the PASTE option, you can try this:

```
override fun getSelectionStart(): Int {
    for (element in Thread.currentThread().stackTrace) {
        if (element.methodName == "canPaste") {
            return -1
        }
    }
    return super.getSelectionStart()
}
```

It is just a hack, but I didn't find anything better.

if you want to disable the menu and cursor completely, you can try following class instead of your EditText:

```
class MaskedCodeEditTextView : EditText {
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {
        init()
        blockContextMenu()
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs) {
        init()
        blockContextMenu()
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyle: Int) : super(
        context,
        attrs,
        defStyle
    ) {
        init()
        blockContextMenu()
    }

    override fun getSelectionStart(): Int {
        for (element in Thread.currentThread().stackTrace) {
            if (element.methodName == "canPaste") {
                return -1
            }
        }
        return super.getSelectionStart()
    }

    private fun setInsertionDisabled() {
        try {
            val editorField = TextView::class.java.getDeclaredField("mEditor")
            editorField.isAccessible = true
            val editorObject = editorField[this]
            val editorClass = Class.forName("android.widget.Editor")
            val mInsertionControllerEnabledField =
                editorClass.getDeclaredField("mInsertionControllerEnabled")
            mInsertionControllerEnabledField.isAccessible = true
            mInsertionControllerEnabledField[editorObject] = false
        } catch (ignored: Exception) {
            // ignore exception here
        }
    }

    private fun blockContextMenu() {
        this.customSelectionActionModeCallback = ActionModeCallbackInterceptor()
        this.isLongClickable = false
        setOnClickListener { v: View? ->
            v?.let {
                if(!it.isFocused) {
                    requestFocus()
                } else {
                    clearFocus()
                    requestFocus()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun isSuggestionsEnabled(): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    private fun init() {
        this.customSelectionActionModeCallback = ActionModeCallbackInterceptor()
        this.isLongClickable = false
    }

    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            setInsertionDisabled()
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event)
    }

    private inner class ActionModeCallbackInterceptor : ActionMode.Callback {
        override fun onCreateActionMode(mode: ActionMode, menu: Menu): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onPrepareActionMode(mode: ActionMode, menu: Menu): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onActionItemClicked(mode: ActionMode, item: MenuItem): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onDestroyActionMode(mode: ActionMode) {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
mEditText.setClickable(false);
mEditText.setEnabled(false);
```

**UPDATE**

Try this solution by Extending the Edittext,

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.ActionMode;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class NoMenuEditText extends EditText
{
private final Context context;

/** This is a replacement method for the base TextView class' method of the same name. This 
 * method is used in hidden class android.widget.Editor to determine whether the PASTE/REPLACE popup
 * appears when triggered from the text insertion handle. Returning false forces this window
 * to never appear.
 * @return false
 */
boolean canPaste()
{
   return false;
}

/** This is a replacement method for the base TextView class' method of the same name. This method
 * is used in hidden class android.widget.Editor to determine whether the PASTE/REPLACE popup
 * appears when triggered from the text insertion handle. Returning false forces this window
 * to never appear.
 * @return false
 */
@Override
public boolean isSuggestionsEnabled()
{
    return false;
}

public NoMenuEditText(Context context)
{
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    init();
}

public NoMenuEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
    this.context = context;
    init();
}

public NoMenuEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
{
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    this.context = context;
    init();
}

private void init()
{
    this.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionModeCallbackInterceptor());
    this.setLongClickable(false);
}


/**
 * Prevents the action bar (top horizontal bar with cut, copy, paste, etc.) from appearing
 * by intercepting the callback that would cause it to be created, and returning false.
 */
private class ActionModeCallbackInterceptor implements ActionMode.Callback
{
    private final String TAG = NoMenuEditText.class.getSimpleName();

    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) { return false; }
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) { return false; }
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) { return false; }
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {}
}
}
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28893714/5870896

Comment: If an `EditText` is not clickable and not enabled, then for all practical purposes it ceases to be an `EditText`. It basically just becomes a `TextView`. I still need to input and select text. I just don't want the system context menu to show.

Comment: @Suragch ow. i thought its an edittext because in your code it is an edittext

Comment: It is an `EditText` still. I just mean that your solution (which does in fact disable the context menu) has the undesirable side effects of not allowing the user to input or select text.

Comment: ow sorry, in my head it was textview but still typing edittext

Comment: Your update looks the same as the code in my question. Is there a difference?

Comment: @Suragch check it again

Comment: I checked it again. When you tested it in the emulator, you weren't getting a popup menu after you clicked the handle of the cursor (as I showed in the image in my question)?