# How to change to text colour of the Cut/Copy/Paste popup menu

Tags: android, colors, app-themes

I have the following in my styles.xml

```
<style name="dialog_style" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorAccent">#ffaaaa00</item>
    <item name="android:background">#ff444400</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#ffa25600</item>
</style>
```

(The horrible colours are for testing only!)

This gives the following

[image]

What I want is a dark/black background but when I do that, the text is unreadable.

Q: How do I change the text colour of "Cut", "Copy"...?

tia,
Kevin

Comment: How did you used this `dialog_style`? In code or xml? If xml, then what attribute did you used?

Comment: Please see my comment re "converting to a fragment"

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a little bit better solution than user3247782's,

```
<style name="CustomAlertDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    ...
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change them by following style names:

```
<item name="colorAccent">@color/twoCuteSelectionHandlersColor</item>
<item name="android:textColorHighlight">@color/selectionColor</item>
```

Also you can set highlight color directly for pacific `EditText` using `android:textColorHighlight` attribute in xml layout or programmatically:

```
et.setHighlightColor(color);
```

For context menu you need create your own context menu. check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41673185/2979171) for how disabling default context menu and implementing custom menu.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer. The black-on-black edit menu is only generated from an EditText contained in an AlertDialog. The same code in a Fragment gives black-on-white.

So I "solved" my problem by converting the AlertDialog into a Fragment.

The original question, though, is still unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

Alert Dialog and Popup Menu generaly take the color of @ColorAccent as the background. So try changing the colorAccent or just inflate a custom xml with the specifications you want.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the parent of it from Theme.Material.Light to Theme.Material . 
It will make the text white, there.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by setting a background color with opacity in the style of the alertdialog

In styles.xml

```
<style name="AppCompatAlertDialogStyle">
...
<item name="android:background">@color/black_overlay</item>
...
</style>
```

In colors.xml

```
<color name="black_overlay">#66000000</color>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `MaterialAlertDialogBuilder` then you can define background color through `colorSurface` attribute.

Then in styles you can just set background to transparent.

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Dialog will use the one define in `colorSurface` and "copy/paste" will use default system colors (e.g. white).