# Kotlin Android - Changing Cut/Copy/Paste text color

Tags: android

Due to

```
<item name="android:backgroundTint">#202030</item>
```

in my style.xml, also background color of Cut/Copy/Paste menu is changed in #202030.

The problem is, the text color of this menu is something like #1a1a1a (it's a default color), so the texts are nearly invisible. How can I change it?

This is my style:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/splash_color</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundTint">#202030</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#1E88E5</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">#202030</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">#1d1d30</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#333333</item>
        <item name="android:timePickerStyle">@style/TimePickerStyleLight</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/product_sans_regular</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#E0E0E0</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">#3399ff</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlActivated">#3399ff</item>
        <item name="alertDialogStyle">@style/AppCompatAlertDialogStyle</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">#BDBDBD</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: It isn't Kotlin question

Comment: Edited title of question.

Comment: Hope this will help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519277/how-to-change-the-text-color-of-menu-item-in-android

Comment: @PranavVR doesn't works for me

Comment: Here is the same question and few suggested solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45766210/4858777

Comment: I've already seen this question, not working for me

Answer (score 0):

```
ToolBar:-    
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/MainActionBar.Popup" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
Style:


    <style name="MainActionBar.Popup" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
            <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
            <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
        </style>
```