# How to disable the double click that selects a word in EditText?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57365263/1062727) answer, I've posted my solution for disable default `copy, paste, select all and clipboard` behaviour for an `EditText`, including disable handle select cursor:

[image: drop]

There are three steps that includes **a)** a short snippet of code (many times posted in *Stackoverflow*); **b)** an empty image and **c)** a custom and global `EditText` style

If one does just step **a**, it keeps on showing the `handle select`. And if one click the handle select, appears the popup with `Clipboard + Select All`  So one should select an empty image associated with the handle select.

However, there is one feature that I can't handle at all:

The `double click` *Android* default behaviour that selects with pink background the clicked word just for a fraction of a second, below showed:

[image: Red Fox]

I've tried many solution proposed in *StackOverflow*, including change `onClick` (plugged by `setOnClickListener`) event for disable  the `TextEdit` control for less than 1 second, using timer or post events.

I also tried handle the cursor in `onTouch` event.

I even try to program a empty `double click` handling in `GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener()`

No success. No clue.

**Update**

For helping clarify, the  features of my problem demand:

1) There is no way to display any extra keys to start typing

2) I need to let the user touch any point of the text, indicating their "insert" position, if applicable. Usually he types at the end of the text and there is no cursor. In that case, I disable it.

3) I need to let the user touch in sequence 2 points of the text, to make a selection, with a marked background. It's not exactly a `double click`, it's two comfortably separate clicks. I don't like `double click` for mobile.

-/-

In short, I need to work with the cursor, but not in the standard way that *Android* offers. Therefore I would need to disable the default *Android* behaviour, but without losing the cursor and the ability to select a piece of text.

-/-

There is an option to make an artificial cursor that blinks, but I imagine it is quite laborious because the cursor don't occupy on character position exactly.

**Update 2**

When I use in `EditText` global style

```
<item name="android:focusableInTouchMode">false</item>
```

The double click becomes inactive, but I cannot show the cursor anymore neither make a selection by software.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

1) Have a TextView showing on the screen (non editable with non of the problems you are explaining).

2) Have a button on the screen that says "start typing" or whatever you want as UX to start the interaction. You could even put the click listener straight on the TextView.

3) Have an offscreen / hidden under another view EditText, that when the OnClick in #2 is triggered will focus on this view - thus popping up the keyboard and starting input.

4) Have a text changed listener on the edittext and whenever they type into the edittext it updates the TextView from #1 with this text.

Thus making the whole thing cursor-less.

Comment: This options are interesting, but unfortunately not for my especific situation. How my issues are a little bit verbose, I will post an update  in the question for helping clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to work around the problem. It is not the most elegant solution that could exist, however it acceptable.

However, I don't go consider a right solution, it is just a trick. It's amazing that apparently has no general solution to turn off word selection by double click.

When I create the `EditText` dinamically, i set

```
tEdit.setHighlightColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)  // tEdit is my TextEdit view
```

When I will select an area  inside my program, I will use *underline* to delimit my selected area, so I keep the highlight color always transparent.

Comment: Your case sounds that custom, you might be better making a source copy of `EditText` and changing it to completely what you want :-) https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/EditText.java

Comment: [Blundell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/413127/blundell), I confess that I am not patient to leave to customize `EditText`. The solution already satisfy me and I confess that I am unwilling to customize `EditText` right now. The solution I found already satisfies me 100% and it's working. I just find surprising that `Google` team don't let customize the copy paste inferface.

Comment: I completely understand :-) enjoy!