# How to Disable copy/paste option of Xamarin forms Entry control in Redmi note 12 pro device?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, miui, redmi-device

I want to **disable copy/paste option** of my **Entry control** in Xamarin forms application. I am using **custom renderer** for that. The current solution is working in all the other devices apart from **Redmi Note 8**. This is my renderer code.

```
class MyEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
    {
      
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control != null)
            {
              Control.CustomSelectionActionModeCallback = new Callback();
                Control.CustomInsertionActionModeCallback = new Callback();

                Console.WriteLine("CustomSelectionActionModeCallback");
                Control.SetTextIsSelectable(false);
                Control.LongClickable = false;
            }
        }
    }
    public class Callback : Java.Lang.Object, ActionMode.ICallback
        {
            public bool OnActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, IMenuItem item)
            {
            Console.WriteLine("OnActionItemClicked");
                return true;
            }
            public bool OnCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, IMenu menu)
            {
            Console.WriteLine("OnCreateActionMode");
            menu.Clear();
            return false;
            }
            public void OnDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            Console.WriteLine("OnDestroyActionMode");
        }
            public bool OnPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, IMenu menu)
            {
            Console.WriteLine("OnPrepareActionMode");
            menu.Clear();
            menu.Close();
            return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

So **long click is getting disabled in Redmi Note 8** but still there is **blue color dot** which appears. On click of that it still shows me copy/paste option. It is **happening only in Redmi note 8**. And in my code no other callback is getting hit other than OnDestroyActionMode and I'm not able to execute menu.Clear.  In other devices that option is getting disabled by using this code

```
Control.SetTextIsSelectable(false);
```

This is how it is getting shown in **Redmi Note 8 device**.

[image]

I have referred these **links** because this **issue is quite similar to mine** but it didn't help.

[Disable EditText context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41673185/9218131)

[EditText: Disable Paste/Replace menu pop-up on Text Selection Handler click event](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27869983/9218131)

As you can see in the image the **paste option is getting shown in the device**. I have no clue how to fix this bug any suggestions?

Comment: What android version is this device? You might need to use a different API to disable the behaviour which will lead to you use conditional compilation `#IF __LOLLIPOP__` .... `#ELIF __PIE__`. Is it the same version as the other devices, if so I would try looking for the appropriate API for that version as things do change & get deprecated etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found **two solutions** for this. One is **clearing the clipboard** and other is **setting the variation of input as visible password**. Both these solutions serves my purpose. For **clearing the clipboard** you can use the following code in your renderer

```
var clipboardManager = (ClipboardManager)Forms.Context.GetSystemService(Context.ClipboardService);
clipboardManager.ClearPrimaryClip();
```

And for **setting the variation of input as visible password** you can use the following code

```
Control.InputType = Android.Text.InputTypes.ClassText | Android.Text.InputTypes.TextVariationVisiblePassword;
```

So these are the solutions which was useful for me.

Comment: Is this a "solution"? You must be kidding.