# Disable copy-paste-sellet all menu when selecting a text

Tags: java, android

I'm building a WebView App where i'm adding my custom menu with copy , paste and other options , now upon clicking , it shows both my custom menu as well as the default menu which shows when we highlight a word .. i would like to know if there is a way to programmatically disable that default menu in my current app , Thank you in advance for any help .

- This is an example of what i mean by default menu ( i want to disable this menu )
  [image]

Comment: Did this Answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41673185/disable-edittext-context-menu

Comment: @Sanjith In my case the copy does not start from edittext , i have no edit text , i have webview and let's for example i have google opened in webview , when the user highlights a text in the entire page , he copies it and that's where the android default menu shows up , exactly like what i'm showing above , no edittext