# Android how to detect Copy event of Edittext in android

Tags: android, events, copy

I have one android apps in that i want : whenever user press copy from the edittext,any event occure, it any of edittext like from messenger edittext,mail edittext any one,when user press copy text, i want to occure any event,so any body give me example for this ?i have no idea about it,so please help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got solutions:
I create one service :
on that in oncreate :

```
         ClipboardManager clipBoard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
         clipBoard.addPrimaryClipChangedListener(new ClipboardListener());
```

and add in service :

```
        class ClipboardListener implements
        ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener {
        public void onPrimaryClipChanged() {
        ClipboardManager clipBoard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        CharSequence pasteData = "";
        ClipData.Item item = clipBoard.getPrimaryClip().getItemAt(0);
        pasteData = item.getText();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "copied val=" + pasteData,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

Comment: How about paste event?

Answer (score 2):

By using the below code for EditText you can get the event for Cut/Copy/Paste.

```
public class EditTextMonitor extends EditText{
private final Context mcontext; // Just the constructors to create a new EditText...

public EditTextMonitor(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.mcontext = context;
}

public EditTextMonitor(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.mcontext = context;
}

public EditTextMonitor(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    this.mcontext = context;
}


@Override
public boolean onTextContextMenuItem(int id) {
    // Do your thing:
    boolean consumed = super.onTextContextMenuItem(id);
    // React:
    switch (id){
        case android.R.id.cut:
            onTextCut();
            break;
        case android.R.id.paste:
            onTextPaste();
            break;
        case android.R.id.copy:
            onTextCopy();
    }
    return consumed;
}

/**
 * Text was cut from this EditText.
 */
public void onTextCut(){Toast.makeText(mcontext, "Event of Cut!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

/**
 * Text was copied from this EditText.
 */
public void onTextCopy(){
    Toast.makeText(mcontext, "Event of Copy!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

/**
 * Text was pasted into the EditText.
 */
public void onTextPaste(){
    Toast.makeText(mcontext, "Event of Paste!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}}
```

Comment: I tested this you can put your won code isted of Toasts.

Comment: or you can see this [link] http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste.html

Comment: it giving me error about empty constructor or required default constructore

Comment: you have to create editText like this   <com.example.test.EditTextMonitor
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="122dp"
        android:ems="10" />   for this edit text you can get cut copy paste events.

Comment: Lets go to use references: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14980227/android-intercept-paste-copy-cut-on-edittext

Comment: Note that in Android O you will also need to include this case:
`case android.R.id.pasteAsPlainText:`