# How to monitor if user copies a text?

Tags: android, listener, clipboard, clipboardmanager

I want to trigger `something` as soon as the user copies a text in his phone.

I was using `ClipboardManager` to get clipboard text at regular intervals to detect any change. I needed the clipboard text anyway.

**However**, this is not what I aimed to do.

What I **actually** want:

To trigger `something` even if the user copies the **same text** again.
Thus, the **clipboard content remains same**, but the user did manually copy some text from his perspective.

***Edit:***

Turns out that `OnPrimaryClipChangedListener` has the same problem. It listens to any **change in clipboard**, and fails if user **copies the same text.**

Comment: I think this is the answer.
[Enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24697236/android-how-to-detect-copy-event-of-edittext-in-android)

Comment: Actually, I tried using the OnPrimaryClipChangedListener already as i wrote in the question. Same issue. It only detects "change". And not whether the user copies something recently or not.