# Android How to set maximum "word" limit on EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, limit, cpu-word

How to set maximum word limit on Android `EditText` I know how to set character limit but I am looking for **Word Limit**.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to add a `TextChangedListener` to your `EditText` then apply an `InputFilter` see the following code.

```
edDesc.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        int wordsLength = countWords(s.toString());// words.length;
        // count == 0 means a new word is going to start
        if (count == 0 && wordsLength >= MAX_WORDS) {
            setCharLimit(edDesc, edDesc.getText().length());
        } else {
            removeFilter(edDesc);
        }

        tvWordCount.setText(String.valueOf(wordsLength) + "/" + MAX_WORDS);
        }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
});

private int countWords(String s) {
    String trim = s.trim();
    if (trim.isEmpty())
        return 0;
    return trim.split("\\s+").length; // separate string around spaces
}

private InputFilter filter;

private void setCharLimit(EditText et, int max) {
    filter = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(max);
    et.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { filter });
}

private void removeFilter(EditText et) {
    if (filter != null) {
        et.setFilters(new InputFilter[0]);
        filter = null;
    }
}
```

You have to intercept Paste event so that user shouldn't be able to paste more than required words. You can intercept Android `EditText` Paste event [[read more]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14981376/185022)

Comment: still you need to see for paste event :)

Comment: it fails when i have typed n words but want to change characters of an existing word. it won't let me type because of character limit filter

Comment: this won't work for the last word, as soon as you add a character the editor won't let you add more characters

Answer (score 3):

**I have made Extension function for the EditText and it works perfectly**

```
fun EditText.addWordCounter(func: (wordCount: Int?) -> Unit) {

addTextChangedListener(object :TextWatcher{
    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {}

    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}

    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
        val trim = s?.trim()
        val wordCount = if (trim?.isEmpty()!!or(false)) 0 else trim.split("\\s+".toRegex()).dropLastWhile { it.isEmpty() }.toTypedArray().size

        func(wordCount)
    }
})}
```

**then use like**

```
etDesc.addWordCounter { wordCount ->
        Log.d(TAG, "addWordCounter: $wordCount")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

binding.etSectionDesc.doAfterTextChanged {
val count = binding.etSectionDesc.content().wordCount()

```
        if (count >= ValidationConst.MAX_COURSE_DESC_LENGTH_SHOW) {
            setCharLimit(binding.etSectionDesc, binding.etSectionDesc.content().length)
        } else {
            removeFilter(binding.etSectionDesc)
        }

        binding.tvDescTotalChar.apply {
            text = count.toString()
            if (count < ValidationConst.MAX_COURSE_DESC_LENGTH_SHOW) {
                setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.black))
            } else {
                setTextColor(context.getAttrResource(R.attr.accentColor_Red))
            }
        }


    }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can Limit the words to type in EditText.

Simply, add this

```
android:maxLength="10"
```

Full code:

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/uname"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:maxLength="10"/>
```

Official Documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:maxLength)

Happy Coding :)

Comment: That sets the maximum number of characters, not words