# OTP entering view without using library in android Kotlin

Tags: android, android-edittext, one-time-password

I want to achieve the below OTP entering view in android.
[image]

I searched for multiple solutions which has another github library or multiple edit texts use which I do not want to do.

How can I customise this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Edit text for OTP with Each letter in separate positions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38872546/edit-text-for-otp-with-each-letter-in-separate-positions)

Answer (score -1):

**Hopefully this will be helpful for you**

> [Edit text for OTP with Each letter in separate positions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38872546/edit-text-for-otp-with-each-letter-in-separate-positions)