# Detect Copy and Paste in an InputField

Tags: c#, android, ios, unity-game-engine

I need to paste the Arabic text into the input field, I can handle it for mac  as there is

```
if (((Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightCommand) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftCommand))
&& Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.V)) || Input.GetMouseButtonUp(1))
{
    inputField.text = ArabicHelper.faConvert(ClipboardHelper.Clipboard);
}
```

I placed this code in the update method and copied text will be in `ClipboardHelper. Clipboard`But how can I recognize that user is pasting some content in iOS or Android is there any events or keys to recognizing that pasting.

Comment: @AustinWBryan, Thanks for responding but how should I change my code, Please suggest me the way to recognize pasting in ios and Android.

Comment: Arent there any detection keys for pasting in devices in unity?

Comment: No. You have to implement that yourself.

Comment: Could you please suggest me any samples on that I have been searching but finding nothing, It would be a great help to me.

Comment: Check back in about 40 minutes. I don't think it's a good idea to do this with `Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightCommand)` even on Desktop devices. I haven't done anything like this before but I will see if I can come up with something.

Comment: Thank you so much, looking really forward for help

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/14981376/7505436

Comment: @vm345 This is Unity and is done with C#. It also has to work with iOS and Android not just Android

Comment: Yes exactly as Programmer said @vm345, I need that should be work for  iOS and Android, Thanks anyway for help.

Comment: I got something. Will test on Android to make sure it works there before posting. If it works on Android then it should on iOS. You will have to do the iOS test yourself. What's your Unity version?

Comment: Sorry for late response @Programmer,this is unity im using 2018.1.0f2

Comment: The proper solution is with `InputField.onValidateInput` but there is a bug with it on Android. It get's called more than it should on Android. The solution I have would have worked on Android but because of this bug, it won't. I don't know if this bug also exist on iOS. Anyways, sorry I can't help at this moment. [Here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1520866/inputfields-onvalidateinput-bug.html) one question about this bug on Android

Comment: Thank you for help @Programmer, I will go through that.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep the current inputted text length in a private variable. Then, once value is changed in the `InputField` (see the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.InputField-onValueChanged.html)), get the new length, compare to the old one and if the length difference is more or equal to 2, player has pasted something. It is impossible to input two characters in single key press.

Comment: Thank you @Tomas Svedas.I will try this way

Comment: I thought about this but how about 1 character paste? You think someone will never paste one character?

Comment: Good point, @Programmer. Though, most people will probably just type the single character instead of pasting it.

Comment: Yes but the most useful case of copying just one char is when you want to copy a char from another language or just a symbol. I do most of them time and it saves time of looking them up or having to change the language of my platform just to get that char from a keyboard.

Comment: What about checking pressed key code, converting it to string and then comparing it with the entered one? If they match - it was typed, if not - it was pasted.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-InputField.html

I would use the On Value Change to call your format method on the InputField every time the user change the text (even when the user just type, not copy&paste).

Just like Tomas Švedas only without check the length.