# Android Copy and Paste by onclick

Tags: android

I am a new android developer. I am trying to make a software which will store password (such as facebook password) of the user. These will be stored and shown as a vertical list view.All these were going properly.

But I want that when anybody will click on one(such as facebook password) of his passwords, that will be copied automatically and pasted on the next clicked edit text field(such as facebook password field) and it can be pasted only once. Once the user paste it, it will be removed from clipboard. But I don't know any method or way to remove the copied data from clipboard after pasting it once by  the user. Please help me.

Comment: I think it is only possible to copy the password to the clipboard: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste.html#Copying
Pasting into another app must be handled by the user itself.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind response -#CHRISTOPHER. But can I enable an option of pasting the code? Such as through a pop up menu?

Comment: Sorry, I don't catch that. You can copy the password to the clipboard by a button click. In the e.g. FB-app the user can long press on the password edittext and choose PASTE. I don't think it is possible to paste the password directly.

Comment: Ow. Thanks. I did not know the long press pasting system of android. Actually I am used to develop android app but not an user of it. I work with my fathers phone. Because I am not 18 yeas old. I am 16. If I disturbed you, please forgive me.I am so  much grateful to you. Again thank you very much. -#Christopher

Comment: I want that a password can be pasted only one time. If user want to paste it again , he must copy it again. Is it possible? @Christopher

Answer (score 2):

Password normally the copy/paste is not enabled for security reasons.

If you want the `onClick` code, I believe this was asked before... let me know if wrong.

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19253868/6723193).

In the onClick:

```
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager)getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText(label, text);
clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
```

Comment: I have understood but now my question is "can I remove the password from clipboard after pasting it once?"

Comment: You can implement a listener in the EditText were is going to be pasted. Like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7271555/6723193) or [this better](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14981376/6723193). And/or implement your own functions of pasting within the app like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19177510/6723193) and make it work like a `OnPasteListener`. Let me know if helped.

Comment: By the way, for removing the string, you can add empty String into the clipboard. More details [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_clipboard.htm).