# Hide Tooltip dialog when phone is in landscape

Tags: android, tooltip, android-sensors, landscape-portrait, sensormanager

> I am using `SensorOrientation` to detect when phone is tilted(in landscape) and show another View when in landScape

**Activity Implementation**

```
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        SensorOrientationChangeNotifier.getInstance(applicationContext).addListener(this)
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        SensorOrientationChangeNotifier.getInstance(applicationContext).remove(this)
    }

    override fun onOrientationChange(orientation: Int) {
        if (orientation == 90 || orientation == 270) {
            this.currentFocus?.let { view ->
               val imm = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as? InputMethodManager
               imm?.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
            }
            binding.cardMemberCard.rootCardView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            Timber.d("onConfigurationChanged onOrientationChange --> ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE")
        } else {
            Timber.d("onConfigurationChanged onOrientationChange --> ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT")
            binding.cardMemberCard.rootCardView.visibility = DrawerLayout.GONE
        }
    }
```

Everything working fine but If any keyboard is open in portrait mode and showing copy cut paste dialog [image: like this]

I want to hide this dialog programmatically on orientation change. I don't want to disable it from start [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275299/how-to-disable-copy-paste-from-to-edittext) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27869983/edittext-disable-paste-replace-menu-pop-up-on-text-selection-handler-click-even)

Initially it should be enable and work but if phone is is in landscape it should hide